# Get Value of Toggle Checkbox in Semantic UI

Tags: jquery, checkbox, semantic-ui

I have a Semantic UI toggle checkbox setup in HTML like this

```
<div class="ui toggle mini checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="myLayer">
    <label>myLayer</label>
</div>
```

And I want to perform some action when the checkbox is either toggled or untoggled. Right now I have this written:

```
$('.ui.toggle').click(function() {
    checked = $('.ui.toggle').is(':checked');
    console.log(checked);
    if (checked === true) {
        myLayer.show();
    }
    else {
        myLayer.hide();
    }
});
```

However, the value of `checked` is always `false`, no matter whether the toggle is on or off! Why is this the case?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The selector `'.ui.toggle'` is referencing the parent container of your input. The right selector would be `'.ui.toggle input'`. Then you also should get a changing value for your variable.

Since you are already in the click handler, it would be even nicer to search for your input this way: `$(this).find('input').is(':checked')`. This way jQuery does not has to parse the whole DOM tree once again to find the input child node.

Answer (score 4):

It'd be better if you init your checkbox with Semantic as followed:

```
$('.ui.toggle').checkbox({
  onChecked: function () { myLayer.show(); },
  onUnchecked: function () { myLayer.hide(); }
});
```

Of course you can always read the value of your checkbox with `.checkbox('is checked')` or `.checkbox('is unchecked')`. To be able to read the value, your checkbox has to be initialized with `$('.ui.toggle').checkbox()`.

For example, this code does the same thing as the segment on top of my answer:

```
$('.ui.toggle').checkbox();

$('.ui.toggle').click(function() {
    if ($('.ui.toggle').checkbox('is checked')) {
        myLayer.show();
    }
    else {
        myLayer.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the best answer since it uses semantic API to query the checkbox: `$(...).checkbox('is checked')`